# Python: Create multiple rows from rows based on columns

Tags: python, group-by, apply

I have a csv file that contains a key-value pair and I am being asked to combine all the values associated with the same key into one row 
For example:

**UPDATE:: Format of sample data**
a csv file with the following data:

```
Key,Link1,Link1S,Link1Dte,Link2,Link2S,Link2Dte,Link3,Link3S,Link3Dte,Link4,Link4S,Link4Dte
 A,A1,S,1/1/2019,C9,T,1/2/2019,C1,N,1/7/2019,C4,W,1/7/2019
 B,A8,S,1/1/2019,C8,W,1/2/2019,,,,,,
 D,A2,S,1/6/2019,C3,T,1/11/2019,D4,W,1/11/2019,,,
```

This should result to the following: RECORDS for the dataframe
   key value

```
Key Leg LegS LegT    NLeg NLegS NLegT
A    A1  S   1/1/19   C9  T     1/2/19
A    C9  T   1/2/19   C1  N     1/7/19
A    C1  N   1/7/19   C4  W     1/7/19
B    A8  S   1/1/19   C8  W     1/2/19
D    A2  S   1/6/19   C3  T     1/11/19
D    C3  T   1/11/19  D4  W     1/11/19
```

As you can see, I needed to transpose a row with a Key value as the first column to multiple rows based on the number of ColXXX values available (which is at most 15 combinations) 
I need to run it to a big file about 200K Key

I was wondering if there is way to do in python without looping through the whole records.. maybe by using a groupby(Key) and then running through the different cols for the Key and then store it in a new dataframe

Comment: Can you format your input data

Comment: @WeNYoBen, i would like to avoid iterations over the pandas dataframe hope u can assist